# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: dotnetnuke

i have downloaded the dotnetnuke application from the clinet server .now i wish to open it in vs2010. for debugging but compiling it is giving this error. i have configured it as the app in iis but same error ? any clue?

Error 1 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Web.config 19

Answer (score 0):

Is that file path correct?  Is `...\Website\WebApplication1\WebApplication1` really the root of your website (in the file system and in IIS)?